# How to edit .replit file to run a custom class

Tags: javafx, replit

I want to run a JavaFX application on replit and the main file there is `App.java` , I want to properly link the application as there is a `module-info.java` file also.

My replit [directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMmpJ.jpg)

Can someone edit(or give me some sources from where I can learn) my `.replit` file such that when I run the application it starts from `App.java` , `module-info.java` is also properly linked and the JDK version should be <16.

I tried understanding the `.replit` file but I can't understand how to edit it.

Here's the code inside file:

```
.compile = "javac --module-path javafx-sdk-18.0.2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls Main.java"
run = "java --module-path javafx-sdk-18.0.2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls Main"

entrypoint = "Main.java"
hidden = ["**/*.class", "javafx-sdk-18.0.2"]

[unitTest]
language = "java"

[nix]
channel = "stable-22_11"

[debugger]
support = true

[debugger.compile]
command = "javac -classpath .:/run_dir/junit-4.12.jar:target/dependency/* -g -d . $(find . -type f -name '*.java')"

[debugger.interactive]
transport = "localhost:0"
connectTimeout = 60
startCommand = "java-debug"

[debugger.interactive.initializeMessage]
command = "initialize"
type = "request"

[debugger.interactive.initializeMessage.arguments]
adapterID = "cppdbg"
clientID = "replit"
clientName = "replit.com"
columnsStartAt1 = true
linesStartAt1 = true
locale = "en-us"
pathFormat = "path"
supportsInvalidatedEvent = true
supportsProgressReporting = true
supportsRunInTerminalRequest = true
supportsVariablePaging = true
supportsVariableType = true

[debugger.interactive.launchMessage]
command = "launch"
type = "request"

[debugger.interactive.launchMessage.arguments]
classPaths = ["."]
mainClass = "Main"
```

Comment: You might get some insight by examining the recipes for other IDEs seen [here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

Comment: @trashgod all I need to know how to edit `.replit` file as it's storing the configurations. I don't know what all editing is required in that file I'll be really thankful if you can share how to change those configurations accordingly as I mentioned.

Comment: maybe try checking out docs for .replit file, it may help configuring, https://docs.replit.com/programming-ide/configuring-repl#replit-reference

Comment: From the replit site: “Write code with Ghostwriter, an AI-powered pair programmer.” -> can your pair not help you with your question?  (honest question).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can make change like so.

`run = "java --module-path javafx-sdk-18.0.2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls Main"` -> `run = "java --module-path javafx-sdk-18.0.2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls App"`

Please note `Main` was updated to `App`.

keep it real!

Comment: I had tried this earlier but this doesn't work I opted to use maven